# VBA How to copy a procedure from an excel-worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, procedure

Copying an entire worksheet is not an option because i have other code that will trigger on change of some cells of the copied sheet and so it will block the copy.

How do I copy the procedures from the first worksheet to another? (after copying all the cells from the first worksheet to a new one)

Comment: You could programmtically move the sheet rather than copy the cells, and then copy the code - unless the "move-to" location is already in use.

Comment: if the code is event code you may be able to use the workbook-level equivalent event; if not, it probably shouldn't be in the sheet anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use various methods in `Application.VBE` which is an object interfacing the visual basic environment: e.g. `Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents` will give you a collection of modules.

To use though users will have to have the "trust access to VBA project" button checked in their security settings (the exact location of this is very version dependent). But note that I disallow this at my firm as it's insecure; and I'm not alone in that.

Are you sure you try (i) switching off calc, (ii) switching off screen updating, (iii) programming blockers into the code that would otherwise run (using, say a boolean)?

Comment: Code that copies code can be detected by virus programs and then removed. This happened to me in this exact situation some years back with xl2003, from memory a McAfee scan thought the VBE code copy bore the marks of the *bloodhound* virus

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I'm a total noob in VBA programming... Screen updating won't work, as the "stopping event" occurs if a cell of the new worksheet changes (which, in fact, does during the copy). Does switching off the calc prevent the worksheet-bound procedure to be executed?
Otherwise I may be forced to use a flag, but let's say I would avoid using another flag since I have many :P

Comment: On balance I'd go with the flag option; but carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to involve any VBA code to actually copy the code! All you need to do is to drag and drop the module(s) in the Visual Basic Editor's "Project Explorer" to the target workbook.

Step by step:

1. Open the Visual Basic Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
2. In the Project Explorer window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>), find the module that contains the code you want to copy
3. Still in the Project Explorer window, drag and drop it to the target workbook, e.g.: [image]

Done!

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I have to do it programmatically... My code must copy 1:1 a worksheet on a button click.

Comment: Then, Bathsheba's answer is the only viable way I'm aware of.